# Refile whole org-mode files as trees?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a directory full of org-mode files. Each file is structured into multiple trees like the following.

> This is the first file
>
> * First item
>   ** Subitem 1
>   ** Subitem 2
>   * Second item

I want to combine all of these files into a single file, where each file has it's own tree. So it would look something like this.

> * file1.org
>   This is the first file
>   ** First item
>   *** Subitem 1
>   *** Subitem 2
>   ** Second item
>   * file2.org
>   This is the second file.
>   ** First item
>   ** Second item
>   ...

What is the easiest way to make this happen using elisp?

Answer (score 2):

This can certainly be improved, but should work pretty well:

```
rm combined.org tmp.org ;
for i in *.org ; do 
    touch combined.org ; 
    echo "* $i" > tmp.org;
    sed "s/^\*/**/" "$i" | cat combined.org tmp.org - > combined.org.tmp ;
    mv combined.org.tmp combined.org ;
done
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I'm guessing that is bash script? I am running Windows and have not managed to get Cygwin working. So, I will edit the question to specify that the solution should use elisp. Thanks though!